# In dplyr, how to drop group with few rows in long format

Tags: r, filter, dplyr

When having long format data with a group variable, is there a direct way to remove all rows of a group that has too few rows? Could we operate on the dataframe directly *without* needing to tally groups first?

Here's an example adapted from [here](https://jennybc.github.io/purrr-tutorial/ls12_different-sized-samples.html):

```r
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(2024)

my_df <-
  iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  nest() %>%            
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(n = sample(1:15, size = 3)) %>% 
  mutate(samp = map2(data, n, sample_n)) %>% 
  select(-data) %>%
  unnest(samp)

my_df
#> # A tibble: 20 x 6
#>    Species        n Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
#>    <fct>      <int>        <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl>
#>  1 setosa         2          5.4         3.9          1.3         0.4
#>  2 setosa         2          5.1         3.8          1.9         0.4
#>  3 versicolor     5          5.5         2.4          3.7         1  
#>  4 versicolor     5          5.5         2.6          4.4         1.2
#>  5 versicolor     5          6           2.7          5.1         1.6
#>  6 versicolor     5          6           2.9          4.5         1.5
#>  7 versicolor     5          5           2            3.5         1  
#>  8 virginica     13          6.4         3.2          5.3         2.3
#>  9 virginica     13          6.4         2.8          5.6         2.1
#> 10 virginica     13          5.7         2.5          5           2  
#> 11 virginica     13          6.3         2.8          5.1         1.5
#> 12 virginica     13          7.2         3.2          6           1.8
#> 13 virginica     13          6.8         3.2          5.9         2.3
#> 14 virginica     13          6.7         3            5.2         2.3
#> 15 virginica     13          7.9         3.8          6.4         2  
#> 16 virginica     13          6.9         3.2          5.7         2.3
#> 17 virginica     13          6.3         3.3          6           2.5
#> 18 virginica     13          6.5         3.2          5.1         2  
#> 19 virginica     13          6.1         2.6          5.6         1.4
#> 20 virginica     13          6.5         3            5.5         1.8
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

---

**My question:** In this example, how can we keep only groups that have more than 10 rows?

---

*my current two-step solution that I dislike*

```r
groups_to_keep <-
  my_df %>%
  count(Species) %>%
  filter(n > 10) %>%
  pull(Species) %>%
  as.character()

> groups_to_keep
## [1] "virginica"

desired_output <-
  my_df %>%
  filter(Species %in% groups_to_keep)

> desired_output
## # A tibble: 13 x 6
##    Species       n Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
##    <fct>     <int>        <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl>
##  1 virginica    13          6.4         3.2          5.3         2.3
##  2 virginica    13          6.4         2.8          5.6         2.1
##  3 virginica    13          5.7         2.5          5           2  
##  4 virginica    13          6.3         2.8          5.1         1.5
##  5 virginica    13          7.2         3.2          6           1.8
##  6 virginica    13          6.8         3.2          5.9         2.3
##  7 virginica    13          6.7         3            5.2         2.3
##  8 virginica    13          7.9         3.8          6.4         2  
##  9 virginica    13          6.9         3.2          5.7         2.3
## 10 virginica    13          6.3         3.3          6           2.5
## 11 virginica    13          6.5         3.2          5.1         2  
## 12 virginica    13          6.1         2.6          5.6         1.4
## 13 virginica    13          6.5         3            5.5         1.8
```

Is there a way to get from `my_df` to `desired_output` directly, without having to create `groups_to_keep`?

Comment: `my_df` has 23 rows and `desired_output` has 24 after filtering? I think you are looking for `my_df %>% group_by(Species) %>% filter(n() > 10)`

Comment: Thanks. I corrected the data in my example. Yes, your solution is what I was looking for. It's indeed a duplicate question.